# PDF invert from white to black background and black to white font - is there an application?

Tags: pdf

If I am reading my PDFs, I am searching for an application to invert my PDF from white background and black font to black background and white font. Is there an application for that?

Very much thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is a night mode option in your default pdf viewer in ubuntu (if you are using it). Go through the file options on the top right you will find it.

In many readers, the shortcut is `ctrl` + `i`.

Comment: I have Evince, it works now. Also it works with ctrl + i. Thank you very much!

Comment: Okular -> settings -> accessibility -> change colors ...

Comment: If this answer helped you, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it, i.e., click the checkmark next to the question. That also hints future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an online application that inverts white and black on PDFs:

https://supertool.org/convert-color-pdfs-to-black-and-white/

It has a "reverse" checkbox that flips the colors.

It works with vector and raster files, which means you can print the result and read it "flipped."

There are also other features that may make reading PDFs easier: changing brightness, converting to true black and white, and a function to change a document to Greyscale.